# how to see contents of the git deleted file (in my case a json file) and then parse it for processing (like cleanups)?

Tags: json, bash, git, shell, github

I have a requirement to trigger clean up tasks by tracking whenever a file is deleted on git master branch.
Secondary task is to convert it to a json file

I have a requirement to trigger clean up tasks by tracking whenever a file is deleted on git master branch.

I dont know if there is a clearer way, but I am trying to workaround  in 3 steps:

1. Get all file nams which were deleted in latest commit:
   `git diff --no-renames --name-only <commit-id (parent hash id in my case)> ^ --diff-filter=D ~/{full path to local folder}`
2. Trying to copy data to a temp file as Json file
3. Use JQ to parse through this temp json file to run cleanup tasks

`git diff -name-only {commit parent hash} --diff-filter=D {folder-name}`

Comment: Do you need to see what the files content was at the time of deletion or just a list of the files deleted in a commit?

Answer (score 1):

> how to see contents of the git deleted file (in my case a json file)
>   and then parse it for processing (like cleanups)?

I'm going to interpret the title as you need to get the contents of a deleted json file from a commit for a cleanup process.  It seems like you already have the commit hash and command to get the file path.

You can use these items to get the file's content at the time of deletion and redirect the output to a temp file

```
git show <commit hash>:<file path> > <temp.json>
```

Or pipe it directly to jq for processing

```
git show <commit hash>:<file path> | jq '.'
```

If I'm missing anything please comment and I'll follow up.